# Software that can convert large amount of data to md5 hash

Tags: text-processing

Currently I have a 2gb database with approximately 100 million lines and I want to convert every single line to md5 hash is there a program that can do it relatively quick.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux there is the command line tool `md5sum`.

You can call it like this:

`echo "test" | md5sum`

Result:

`d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249`

Comment: Still that is only useful if I have a small quantity

Comment: @BataBo you could try tricks by combining `md5sum` with `xargs` and GNU `parallel` but your post was referring to any OS environment so my response was also generic.